# Get return code of disowned background process

Tags: bash, background-process, nohup

My process is created using nohup and will be disowned to make it independant from killing of its parent process.

I need the return code of this backgroud process, which was disowned and nohuped:

```sh
nohup bash -c 'exit 123' "$@" >log.txt 2>&1 </dev/null &
pid=$!
disown $pid
tail --pid=$pid -f log.txt
```

Now the script will return 0. But it should return the exit code of my process started using `nohup`.

- `wait $pid` doesn't work and always returns 0.

How to get the exit code of the process?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found a solution by using setsid insteed of nohup and disown:

```sh
setsid bash -c 'exit 123' "$@" >log.txt 2>&1 </dev/null &
pid=$!
tail --pid=$pid -f log.txt
wait $pid
```

Now it returns the exit code of my background process and it still ignores killing of the parent process.